# Visual C++ 6.0 "this file is already open in an editor "

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

today i received the source code of an old program made to control an equipment we need.
The code is in Visual C++ 6.0.
I installed Visual Studio 6.0 enterprise in my PC.

When i open the workspace, i can view the source code but when i go to "Resources" tab, i receive the error message "this file is already open in an editor". So i'm not able to modify dialog windows.

I already tried to search for similar problem. I think there is some file where it is registered as open... but i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is it possible that you have opened the rc file in text mode (code)?

Comment: You can open a .rc file with the text editor or with the graphical resource editor.  It is telling you that you can do both at the same time.